# Why are some of my Google Vision API DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION results' normalizedVertices greater than 1?

Tags: rest, api, ocr, google-vision

I have implemented an OCR invoice solution using Google Vision API DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION service. The software has been in production for a couple months. 99% of the time, the results are pretty accurate. But every once in a while, I get some results containing normalizedVertices with points greater than 1. According to the docs, a normalized vertex should be between 0 and 1. Anyone know why this happens? And how these should be interpreted?

Only thing I have noticed (in conjunction with this issue) is that often the documents producing these results may be rotated. But I don't see why rotation would cause the normalization to be off.

[Here's a sample file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/11kkvTQ_NNyy2bDIb201cJNQPY2qoP6oN/view?usp=sharing)

```
{
    "fullTextAnnotation": {
        "pages": [
            {
                "property": {
                    "detectedLanguages": [
                        {
                            "languageCode": "en",
                            "confidence": 0.84
                        },
                        {
                            "languageCode": "da",
                            "confidence": 0.01
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "width": 612,
                "height": 792,
                "blocks": [
                    {
                        "boundingBox": {
                            "normalizedVertices": [
                                {
                                    "x": 1.2254902,
                                    "y": 0.79545456
                                },
                                {
                                    "x": 1.2254902,
                                    "y": 0.9166667
                                },
                                {
                                    "x": 1.1960784,
                                    "y": 0.9166667
                                },
                                {
                                    "x": 1.1960784,
                                    "y": 0.79545456
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "paragraphs": [
                            {
                                "boundingBox": {
                                    "normalizedVertices": [
                                        {
                                            "x": 1.2254902,
                                            "y": 0.79545456
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "x": 1.2254902,
                                            "y": 0.9166667
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "x": 1.1960784,
                                            "y": 0.9166667
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "x": 1.1960784,
                                            "y": 0.79545456
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                "words": [
                                    {
                                        "property": {
                                            "detectedLanguages": [
                                                {
                                                    "languageCode": "en"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        "boundingBox": {
                                            "normalizedVertices": [
                                                {
                                                    "x": 1.2254902,
                                                    "y": 0.79545456
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "x": 1.2254902,
                                                    "y": 0.9166667
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "x": 1.1960784,
                                                    "y": 0.9166667
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "x": 1.1960784,
                                                    "y": 0.79545456
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        "symbols": [
                                            {
                                                "property": {
                                                    "detectedLanguages": [
                                                        {
                                                            "languageCode": "en"
                                                        }
                                                    ]
                                                },
                                                "text": "I",
                                                "confidence": 0.99
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "property": {
                                                    "detectedLanguages": [
                                                        {
                                                            "languageCode": "en"
                                                        }
                                                    ]
                                                },
                                                "text": "N",
                                                "confidence": 1
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "property": {
                                                    "detectedLanguages": [
                                                        {
                                                            "languageCode": "en"
                                                        }
                                                    ]
                                                },
                                                "text": "V",
                                                "confidence": 0.99
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "property": {
                                                    "detectedLanguages": [
                                                        {
                                                            "languageCode": "en"
                                                        }
                                                    ]
                                                },
                                                "text": "O",
                                                "confidence": 0.99
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "property": {
                                                    "detectedLanguages": [
                                                        {
                                                            "languageCode": "en"
                                                        }
                                                    ]
                                                },
                                                "text": "I",
                                                "confidence": 0.99
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "property": {
                                                    "detectedLanguages": [
                                                        {
                                                            "languageCode": "en"
                                                        }
                                                    ]
                                                },
                                                "text": "C",
                                                "confidence": 0.99
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "property": {
                                                    "detectedLanguages": [
                                                        {
                                                            "languageCode": "en"
                                                        }
                                                    ],
                                                    "detectedBreak": {
                                                        "type": "LINE_BREAK"
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                "text": "E",
                                                "confidence": 1
                                            }
                                        ],
                                        "confidence": 0.99
                                    }
                                ],
                                "confidence": 0.99
                            }
                        ],
                        "blockType": "TEXT",
                        "confidence": 0.99
                    },...
```

Comment: Are you able to create a sample pdf that has the issue that you can share?

Comment: Thanks @Brendan - I have added a sample file :)

Comment: My assumption; When the image has to be rotated to be upright, than the rotated image will always be larger than the original image to not crop parts of the original image. Therefore the coordinates in the rotated image might be greater than 1.0 if the API calculates these vertices relative to the size of the original image.